# How to link a character from a file to another one with auto-rig pro

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, auto-rig-pro

I'm following the tutorial called **battle scene in blender** that you can watch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycIABofYkgE). At some point the creator says : "the skeletons for both characters have to be inside the same armature",so this is what I want to do,using the rigging system **auto-rig pro by artell**.

So,I have created and rigged two different characters. The first character,called **Ely** is located inside the blender file called **Ely_auto-rig-pro6** and the second one,called John is located inside the blender file called **John_auto-rig-pro7**. Now,what I want to do is to **link** the character called **John** inside the **scene 1** of the blender file called **Ely_auto-rig-pro6**. Artell gave to me the following [tutorial](http://lucky3d.fr/auto-rig-pro/doc/#linking) for learn how to do it.

So I tried,but a nightmare is happened...I don't know how to goes further. Can someone give to me some suggestion ? I've attached all the materials that you need ; the two blender files and a short recorded video that shows what I did. Here you can see the madness that's happened...

[image: madness]

You can find all the material that you need [here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f7I78RVDs3n__5oDN10vG6wa5Ar0gRRN)

Comment: You have to understand that not many people uses that paid  addon, and as a paid tool, it could have its own specific support available...

Comment: I understand this,but I also think that someone may use it. Who knows ? maybe I found someone. BTW I have no alternative...he replied giving to me some help,but I'm too much newbie to do by myself..I write here what should I do...

Comment: I can't guarantee anything if you decide to merge two ARP armatures together. The rigs are complex and rely on several layers/bones, so this may or may not work.

Comment: It works with several characters, but the characters must be in the world center (0,0,0) when retargetting, that's the only requirement. Then after retargetting you can move the "char_grp" empty object of the character (root object in the outliner) to move the whole character, or you can move the c_traj/c_pos bones controller on the ground.

Comment: It seems active layer is not unchecked when you append/link the character. So the UI objects in the last layers are visible... Look for this checkbox in the bottom left area when appending: